# Foundations Contact Form

Tags: php, contact-form

I am using Foundations V5, The website works prefect except the contact us form. The form will produce a success send but the in email there is no typed information. I can upload the site if anyone needs it.

### This is the PHP Mailer

```
    <?php

$name = $_POST['yourName'];
$email = $_POST['yourEmail'];
$message = $_POST['yourMessage'];

$msg = "
    Name: $name
    Email: $email
    Comments: $message
    ";

$to      = 'Musicdiaries@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';
//$message = $msg;
$headers = 'From: contact@DigitalONEProductions.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

---

Comment: What does your HTML form look like? (can you post your HTML form code in the question above?)

Comment: I tired that and it didn't work and not it won't send the email :-$

Comment: What is the question? This is just php not zurb-foundation.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection that may turn your server into a spammer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection